# What is the referent of "it" in "under it"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, antecedents

The following quote is from *Mansfield Park* by Jane Austen:

> Mr. Crawford, approaching Julia, said: "I hope I am not to lose my companion, unless she is afraid of the evening air in so exposed a seat."  The request had not been foreseen, but was very graciously received, and Julia's day was likely to end almost as well as it began.  Miss Bertram had made up her mind to something different, and was a little disappointed; but her conviction of being really the one preferred comforted her **under it**, and enabled her to receive Mr. Rushworth's parting attentions as she ought.

My question is: what is the referent of it in *under it*?  What does *under it* mean?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "conviction of being really the one" did the comforting. The thing that she was "under" and so needed comforting was her disappointment at not getting the "something different" referred to earlier.

So, she is under her disappointment, and being preferred comforts her.

And I learned that I don't need to read any Jane Austen. That paragraph was painful.